# Typedef enum declaration in C++

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

My question is simple.
Is it legal in C++ to postpone the typedef in a declaration like the following? gcc accepts the code without problems, but is it a deprecated way? I ask this because I found every time samples with typedef at the beginning of the instruction.

```
enum _mytype {   
 A=1,   
 B=2 
} typedef mytype;
```

Comment: It's legal C++ syntax (per the grammar, that `typedef` is `decl'ion-seq -> decl'ion -> block-decl'ion -> simple-decl'ion -> decl-spec-seq -> decl-spec`), but I'm not sure that the semantics are well-defined.

Comment: You realize that this kind of typedef convention is obsolete in C++ right? There's no longer any temptation to do something like typedef st_foo {...} foo; in C++ as it's not short-handing anything: we can write 'foo' without 'struct foo' either way. Likewise no need for something like typedef en_foo {...} foo; for the same reason. Actually that's not even a recommended C convention to hide away 'struct' or 'enum' with typedefs according to BUFB aka Expert C Programming.

Comment: And using identifers starting with an underscore is not a good idea.

Comment: In C, `typedef` is treated as a storage class specifier (only for syntactic convenience), and placing a storage class specifier other than at the beginning of a declaration is an obsolescent feature.  I don't think there's a similar statement in the C++ standard.

Comment: This is the most confusing syntax. You are saving one line. Plus your variable name stinks (_mytype vs mytype). Why not just save yourself the trouble and give the enum a proper name such as `ABList` and then you don't need the typedef. The only time I would use typedef is on a type a compiler does not support or on say a vector declaraction like: `typedef vector<Polygon> PolygonColl` so I don't have to use the `vector<Polygon>` in method parameters, I can just use `PolygonColl thePolygons`.

Answer (score 4):

`typedef X Y;`

and

`X typedef Y;`

are just two ways to write the exactly same thing in C++. Neither is deprecated, it is just that the first is much more commonly used, maybe because you can read it as "typedef X as Y".

Comment: +1. I once did the latter style to irritate one of my co-workers who had an annoying habit of using 1-space indents on his code along with modifying my code already using 4-space indents that way.

Comment: @stinky472: You should both be using tab indents. Space indents are the annoying habit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Blargh. It depends on whether you prefer consistency across editors or not. Hopefully we can agree that at least tabs are bad for anything but left indentation (not something like aligning a bunch of variable names) as the latter would wreak havoc on the formatting of the code unless the whole team standardized on the number of spaces that represent a tab.

Comment: @stinky472: Wow, I can see the battle of da codez. Good, why make code more readable when you can make it less so? The ultimate goal must be that of utter and complete unreadability! Here's a hint for you how to win: Compile your coworker's code. Select some functions and locate the binary code for those. Export the binary blob to a C byte array. Replace the functions with function pointers pointing to the correspondent array. Win!

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson Actually I did it only in some select cases as a joke since he had a bad habit of reformatting everything he touched. I thought by confusing him a bit, it might slow down the damage. He's not with us anymore mainly because he didn't understand the whole point of modular design and would even go against design intentions by doing things like casting away const left and right (one man's constant is another man's variable). :-D ... but that's another story.

Comment: @stinky472: `Hopefully we can agree that at least tabs are bad for anything but left indentation (not something like aligning a bunch of variable names)` Yep. Tabs are for indentation but not for alignment

Comment: Note that the latter form _is_ deprecated in C.  In C (but not in C++), `typedef` is considered a _storage-class_, and putting _storage-class_ other than as the first element is deprecated.  (The deprecation isn't in C++ either.)

Comment: I'd like to see some standard reasoning in this answer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In face of a missing standard for the meaning of tabs, most coding guidelines rightly forbid them in source code.  They cause nothing but trouble.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Complete nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What's complete nonsense?  Tab's just don't work in practice, because there is no standard for them.  (Most applications treat tab's as 8, but there are enough exceptions to make it painful.  And who wants to indent 8 characters anyway.)

Comment: @James: The whole point is that you can render them in any way you like. If you configure your editor to render them as a mess then that's your own fault. Tab indentation itself is _the_ clean and atomic solution. Of course there's a standard: one tab per indentation level. It doesn't get any better than that!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I work for a large corporation with thousands of engineers and tabs are explictly forbidden. I think its safe to say that tabs are the devil.

Comment: @0A0D: What, because some megacorporation doesn't allow them? That doesn't follow, logically. By that logic, the Win32 API is the best piece of design in the world. I've never heard *any* rational justification against tab indentation, whilst their benefits are blatantly obvious.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit: Their benefits stink and most people are against them. You are in the minority. Most companies coding standards forbid them.

Comment: @0A0D: Sure, a consistent, semantic standard and the ability to render as you please "stinks". Screw that, eh? I've never seen a corporate coding standard that doesn't itself "stink". I dispute your assertion that I'm in the minority, but I can't prove that I'm not, so. Whatever.

Comment: Though a (relatively) small sample size, [this question at least](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e) indicates that I am far from a minority, so I do question the veracity of your claims. Being a corporation or being famous doesn't make your coding standard "right" or "most people"

Comment: You can disagree as this is a sort-of longstanding religious war and that is fine. I think you'll find that tabs are the gift of satan in code and that you are better off with spaces in the long run. Many corporations are successful for a reason. At any rate, choose what coding standard your company chooses to go with, whether it is right or not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can configure them in my editor, but not in the 20 or 30 other tools I use to look at source code.  And of course, what do you do if different source files require them configured differently?  The fact remains that tab's are an unendless source of problems in any real development environment, where many different developers are using many different tools.

Comment: @0A0D "choose what coding standard your company chooses to go with": Agreed.  Probably the reason I feel so strongly on the issue is because my current employer does impose tabs, and they do cause no end of problems.  The reality of the situation is that there is no advantage in using tabs, but lot's of disadvantages.

Comment: @JamesKanze: My only complaint about tabs is that they are inconsistent. I like space ident of 3 spaces. Some people argue that tabs are 1 byte and 3 spaces are 3 bytes. Sure, that's true but memory and hard drive space is cheap so bickering over bytes saved by using tabs far exceeds the clear use of spaces in code. Plus, using tabs is harder to do when you are trying to keep it within 80 characters.

Comment: @0A0D My complaint about tabs is that so many programs handle them differently.  `diff` output, for example.  Any program, in fact, which prefixes characters to the line to highlight something.  And you don't always control the rendering: `xterm` handles them differently than the editor in VS.

Comment: @0A0D: No, they are by definition consistent. One tab per indentation level, always. There is no _room_ for inconsistency in that scheme. And coding to a strict 80-character width in this day and age is ridiculous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Different programs expand tabs differently.  Like it or not, tab's make things more difficult in practice, for no gain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An 80 character limit is quite convenient if you only have one screen to work on.  It allows two open windows, side by side.  One for the shell, and one for the editor, for example.  (Long lines are also harder to read, but the limit there is something even less than 80 characters.  And I'm not sure it applies to things like code.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No it's not. Scrolling sucks. I want to see the code right in front of me as its easier to read and understand. I don't want to scroll left and right. It has nothing to do with the size of screens.

Comment: @0A0D: What?! How does not wanting to scroll have nothing to do with the size of screens??????? The size of screens _defines_ when it is that scrolling comes into play. We probably shouldn't be discussing this here, which is convenient because I'm starting to go mad! :)

Comment: Long lines that span too far across the monitor are hard to read. This is typography 101. The shorter your line lengths, the less your eye has to travel to see it.

If your code is narrow enough, you can fit two files on screen, side by side, at the same time. This can be very useful if you’re comparing files, or watching your application run side-by-side with a debugger in real time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Plus, if you write code 80 columns wide, you can relax knowing that your code will be readable and maintainable on more-or-less any computer in the world.

 For example, if you’re using 8-space tabs and an 80-column page width, code within a class, a method, and an if statement will already have almost a third of the available space taken for indentation.

Comment: @0A0D: But you wouldn't have 8-space tabs. That's ridiculous. And if the code uses tabs then _you get to choose what width they are_ for your screen/window/monitor/eyes/brain. If somebody has used spaces, _then you cannot_. That is the whole point. In closing, I refer you to my previous comment, by respectfully and firmly disagreeing, and suggesting to leave it that way for today.

Comment: @0A0D: LOL, 3 spaces? You're in the minority there friend. Anyways while there are issues with using tabs it's quite possible with diligent programmers to use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment and it won't cause a problem no matter what editor or tool you use to view the files in. I've been involved in a larger project where this was done, mainly because there were no company standard in place and once standardization started, none of the programmers could agree on the indentation depth.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson: I doubt it. Maybe in Sweden.

Answer (score -2):

In C you often use

```
typedef enum 
{
} what_ever;
```

because in C "enum what_ever" would define a type "enum what_ever" and not "what_ever". However in C++ this is not the case and besides for backwards compatibility reasons you should not use typedef in this situation when writing C++.

Comment: I think you ought to read the question again; I don't think you've answered it at all.